# How to see what's going in background when we run a .sh file in Linux?

Tags: shell-script

I know one way i.e. `./filename.sh > log.txt`. But that log file is containing the content what appears in console if we run the file using `./filename.sh`.

Background process is not appearing in log file. By "background process" I mean how compiler is evaluating each and every line (the word "debug" suits that, I guess).

How to get that background process into a log file?

Comment: What do you mean by "background process"?

Comment: how compiler is evaluating each and every line (The word Debug suits to that  I guess, But not sure)

Comment: What compiler? There's no mention of any compiler in your question.

Comment: I'm sry.. I have talked in view of java. So used the word Compiler..  I mean I would like to know 'How bash is executing each and every line of shell script' when running a .sh file..

Comment: You mean source code of shell ? that's very broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I mean I would like to know 'How bash is executing each and every line of shell script' when running a .sh file..

If you are using bash, then what you're looking for is:

```
bash -x ./filename.sh
```

or

```
bash -x ./filename.sh > log.txt
```

Alternatively you can add:

```
set -x
```

to the content of `filename.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the script (after Shebang) add the line:

```
exec >/path/to/log.txt
```

to redirect STDOUT of the script to `/path/to/log.txt`.

If you want to redirect both STDOUT and STDERR:

```
exec >/path/to/log.txt 2>&1
```

Or just STDERR:

```
exec 2>/path/to/log.txt
```

Now regardless of the script being in foreground or background, the log file will have the STDOUT (and/or STDERR).